# Depend of screen size, merge menu's items to dropdown. Without jquery

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

For example I have menu with items:

1)[image]

When I change browser's size, two last items merged two 1 dropdown

2)[image]

3)[image]

I need something like this. I have got **Contacts_France | Contacts_Germany** and when size will be decreased they are should be merged to one dropdown with name **Contacts**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MAx-nax</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact_france">Contact_France</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact_germany">Contact_Germany</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use pure javascript?

Comment: @ChrisHappy yep!!!

Comment: Sweet. Could you post some the HTML of the menu? Or would you prefer that I make some up?

Comment: @ChrisHappy done. As you can see after resizing I want to merge `<li><a href="#contact_france">Contact_France</a></li> ` and
               `<li><a href="#contact_germany">Contact_Germany</a></li>` to one dropdown with name **Contacs** for example.

Comment: Sorry, didn't reply...working...

Comment: @ChrisHappy don't worry! Anyway thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#!/" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
                    <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">`enter code here`
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Germany</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">France</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Poland</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Czech Republic</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Romania</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Moldova</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown hidden-xs hidden-lg hidden-md">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Western Europe<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu hidden-xs hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">France</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown hidden-xs hidden-lg hidden-md">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">East Europe<b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu hidden-xs hidden-lg hidden-md">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Czech Republic</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Romania</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Moldova</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Name</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-xs hidden-lg"></a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-xs hidden-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-xs hidden-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm hidden-md">Setting</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm hidden-md">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br/>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi there is a variant to solve and so the given task. Without js. Twitter-Bootstrap. You can control everything with "hidden". Reduce the browser and you'll see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>A [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/e34p0t6w/) to easy resizable ability. Right now, there's some crazy switching in the more menu during the resize event. I have no idea why it's happening...</strike>

**EDIT**: Able to solve with [@Santiago Rebella's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742269#44743571) solution here.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e34p0t6w/3/)

```js
var tele = document.getElementById('teleporter'),
  rec = document.getElementById('receiver');

window.onresize = resize;
resize();

function resize() {
  const rChildren = rec.children;
  let numW = 0;

  [...rChildren].forEach(item => {
    item.outHTML = '';
    tele.appendChild(item);
  })

  const teleW = tele.offsetWidth,
    tChildren = tele.children;

  [...tChildren].forEach(item => {
    numW += item.offsetWidth;

    if (numW > teleW) {
      item.outHTML = '';
      rec.appendChild(item);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#teleporter {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="teleporter">
        <li>List item 0</li>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
        <li>List item 4</li>
        <li>List item 5</li>
        <li>List item 6</li>
        <li>List item 7</li>
        <li>List item 8</li>
        <li>List item 9</li>
        <li>List item 10</li>
        <li>List item 11</li>
        <li>List item 12</li>
        <li>List item 13</li>
      </ul>
      <div>More:
        <ul id="receiver"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

How to use this code for it.

```js
var tele = document.getElementById('teleporter'),
  rec = document.getElementById('receiver');

window.onresize = resize;
resize();

function resize() {
  const rChildren = rec.children;
  let numW = 0;

  [...rChildren].forEach(item => {
    item.outHTML = '';
    tele.appendChild(item);
  })

  const teleW = tele.offsetWidth,
    tChildren = tele.children;

  [...tChildren].forEach(item => {
    numW += item.offsetWidth;

    if (numW > teleW) {
      item.outHTML = '';
      rec.appendChild(item);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#teleporter {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="teleporter">
        <li>List item 0</li>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
        <li>List item 4</li>
        <li>List item 5</li>
        <li>List item 6</li>
        <li>List item 7</li>
        <li>List item 8</li>
        <li>List item 9</li>
        <li>List item 10</li>
        <li>List item 11</li>
        <li>List item 12</li>
        <li>List item 13</li>
      </ul>
      <div>More:
        <ul id="receiver"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```