# Element Order being Messed Up from after Moving Elements Twice

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm making creating some Javascript code so that the overflowing menu links would move into a separate menu called more.

The first time it is loaded, it works perfectly. However, when it is run again, things start shuffling...

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/e34p0t6w/2/)

Snippet here:

```js
var tele = document.getElementById('teleporter'),
   rec = document.getElementById('receiver');

window.onresize = resize;
resize();

function resize() {
  var rChildren = rec.children,
     numW = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < rChildren.length; i++) {
    var child = rChildren[i];
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment().appendChild(child);
    child.outHTML = '';
    tele.appendChild(fragment);
  }
  
  var teleW = tele.offsetWidth,
     tChildren = tele.children;

  for (var i = 0; i < tChildren.length; i++) {
    var child = tChildren[i];
    numW += child.offsetWidth;

    if (numW > teleW) {
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment().appendChild(child);
      child.outHTML = '';
      rec.appendChild(fragment);
      i--;
    }
  }
  
}
```

```css
#teleporter {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="teleporter">
  <li>List item 0</li>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
  <li>List item 5</li>
  <li>List item 6</li>
  <li>List item 7</li>
  <li>List item 8</li>
  <li>List item 9</li>
  <li>List item 10</li>
  <li>List item 11</li>
  <li>List item 12</li>
  <li>List item 13</li>
</ul>
<div>More:
  <ul id="receiver"></ul>
</div>
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Without reading the full code, don't you want to append the child when moving from second menu to the first, and inserting as the first one when moving from first to second?

Comment: Hmm.... I don't think that'll work during the first load, but I that was definitely what I was missing.... Thanks!

Comment: @Icepickle Looking at it again, I realized that shouldn't actually be a problem. The first for loop should reset it to what it was originally and the second one sorts it.

Comment: `.outHTML` do mean `.outerHTML`? If so, `child.outerHTML = '';` will just remove `child`.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your resize function to avoid for loops, most probably error is in the hoisting of your i's, and unless you are doing it for a specific reason you can avoid the fragment variable, find below the modified resize, works

```
      function resize() {
        const rChildren = rec.children;
        let numW = 0;

        [...rChildren].forEach(item => {
          item.outHTML = '';
          tele.appendChild(item);
        })  

        const teleW = tele.offsetWidth,
          tChildren = tele.children;

        [...tChildren].forEach(item => {
          numW += item.offsetWidth;

          if (numW > teleW) {
            item.outHTML = '';
            rec.appendChild(item);
          }
        });
      }
```

updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e34p0t6w/3/

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand about half of the code, but I'm still wondering why in the world it's not working.... Still, great answer +1

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the `<li>` are always in order, we make each `<ul>` a flex container and then assign each `<li>` the CSS property [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Collect all <li> into an array
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
// Assign each <li> the CSS property {order: index}
items.forEach((item, index) => item.style.order = index);

// Bind the window to the resize event
window.onresize = resize;
// Call resize() for an initial sizing
resize();

function resize(e) {
  // Reference both <ul>
  const tX = document.querySelector('.tX');
  const rX = document.querySelector('.rX');
  // Get the width of tX
  let tXW = tX.offsetWidth;
  // Getv the width of the first <li>
  let itemW = document.querySelector('li').offsetWidth;
  /* 
  Divide the current width of tX by the width of a <li>
  the result is the number of <li> that can fit in tX
  in a single line
  */
  let tXTotal = Math.floor(tXW / itemW) - 1;

  /*
  First array are the first <li> up to the last <li> that
  can fit inside of tX
  Second array is the remaining <li>
  */
  let tXArray = items.slice(0, tXTotal);
  let rXArray = items.slice(tXTotal);

  // Append the array of <li> to the appropriate <ul>
  tXArray.forEach(item => tX.append(item));
  rXArray.forEach(item => rX.append(item));
}
```

```css
all {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 5vh 15vw 5vw 10vh;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.tX {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 75vw;
  height: 20px;
  padding-right: 25vw;
}

.rX {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

li {
  min-width: max-content;
  margin: 0 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul class="tX">
    <li>List item 00</li>
    <li>List item 01</li>
    <li>List item 02</li>
    <li>List item 03</li>
    <li>List item 04</li>
    <li>List item 05</li>
    <li>List item 06</li>
    <li>List item 07</li>
    <li>List item 08</li>
    <li>List item 09</li>
    <li>List item 10</li>
    <li>List item 11</li>
    <li>List item 12</li>
    <li>List item 13</li>
  </ul>
  <div>More:
    <ul class='rX'></ul>
  </div>
</main>
```